# not able to read a split file from a large binary file python

Tags: python, file, split, binary

I have generated few small binary file from a huge pickle binary file. Using the following code

```
inputfile="IDS.p"    
with open(inputfile, 'rb') as file_object:
    
    line_count = 0
    for line in file_object:
        if line != "\n":
            line_count += 1
    line_count=line_count+1
lines_per_file = line_count//6
smallfile = None
with open(inputfile, 'rb') as bigfile:
    for lineno, line in enumerate(bigfile):
        if lineno % lines_per_file == 0:
            if smallfile:
                smallfile.close()
            small_filename = 'small_file_{}.p'.format(lineno + lines_per_file)
            smallfile = open(small_filename, 'wb+')
        smallfile.write(line)
    if smallfile:
        smallfile.close()
```

I get the output files as below:
[image]

I can read the first file fine as below:

```
input_file='small_file_47377391.p'        
l=[]        
with open(input_file, 'rb') as signal_in:
    while True:
        try:
            item = cPickle.load(signal_in)
            len_events=[i.split('_')[-2] for i in item.keys()]   
            l.append(len_events[0])
        except:
            break
```

However, I am not able to read any of the other files. For example when I read the next file small_file_94754782.p, I get nothing in my list l.

Can someone please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you reading a binary file by lines? That's only meaningful for text files.

Comment: Why are you doing this in Python? There's a `split` command that will split up a binary file.

Comment: Thanks Barmar. I tried split command as well, but same issue. Its able to read the first small file but not the others. Seems very weird but not able to figure out what's happening. I am reading it line by line because I want to perform downstream function per line. Thanks

Comment: You can't use `cPickle.load()` on a partial file.

Comment: I see. Thanks. Any other option to load it line by line ?